# Trouble installing keras

Tags: python, keras, pip

I have a problem with keras; I've installed it once but somehow I cannot import it anymore since I recently installed some other packages. If I want to import keras, I get the following error (among many other warnings etc.):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tsl'
```

I tried to force reinstall both keras and tensorflow but if I want to do this with keras (with the command `pip install --force-reinstall keras`), I get the following errors

```
This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.7.0 requires flatbuffers<3.0,>=1.12, but you have flatbuffers 22.11.23 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.7.0 requires keras<2.8,>=2.7.0rc0, but you have keras 2.11.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.7.0 requires tensorflow-estimator<2.8,~=2.7.0rc0, but you have tensorflow-estimator 2.11.0 which is incompatible.
```

And if I want to force reinstall tensorflow I get the following error

```
Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert: 'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-tbtwxjcv\\core\\_multiarray_tests.cp38-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I truly have no idea what is happening here; is it possible to delete the packages manually to reinstall them afterwards? Also the simple `pip uninstall`does not work... Initially I installed keras without a virtual environment, i.e. just with `pip install keras', but it worked once at least...

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade `Tensorflow` or downgrade `keras`

```
pip install keras==2.8
```

and do the same for the other two libraries

Comment: Thanks! The issue is that if I downgrade keras, it gives me the same error as for the force reinstall, same happens if I want to upgrad Tensorflow - The problem seems to be more involved; maybe it would be smarter to deinstall it somehow manually (since pip uninstall does not work as well) @Maen